# Trying to modify Liferay's classic theme is behaving rare

Tags: liferay, war, liferay-theme, liferay-ide, liferay-7

I have a Liferay 6.1 instance with a custom classic theme, but trying to upgrade it to 7.0 is being so painful that I decided to take Liferay 7's classic theme (downloaded from [here](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-frontend-theme/tree/master/frontend-theme-classic)).

To bring it into Eclipse - Liferay IDE I created a new module (theme) project and imported files, but trying to deploy it was sending errors (for example, no init.ftl, stuff like that, unexpected given I am using the repo source).

When I arrived to this error, solved it and tried to deploy, it again said there's no init.ftl... Then I searched for it into the war and it actually wasn't there! No idea about what but... I noticed a portal_pop_up.ftl that doesn't exist in my source code!!! What is going on? I'm pretty confused.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was with code downloaded from Github.

If you want to use classic-theme, just create an "empty" theme in the IDE and then overwrite it's files with the ones from auto"deployed" classic-theme in the L7 instance, in /opt/liferay/osgi/wabs.